# Can't show googlemap using primefaces in jsf

Tags: google-maps, jsf, primefaces

I want to using primeface to show google map in jsf, and i added these lines

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript"  
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">  </script>
```

and

```
      <p:gmap center="41.381542, 2.122893" zoom="15" type="HYBRID"   
    style="width:600px;height:400px" />
```

but it can't show, i don't know why. How can i solve it, thank for helping.

Comment: Open JSF page in webbrowser, rightclick and *View Source*. What do you see in place of `<p:gmap>`? Do you still see the unparsed/unexecuted `<p:gmap>` tag or do you see its generated HTML output?

Comment: try putting the <p:map> inside an <f:view contentType="text/html"> element

Comment: I put it inside an <f:view contentType="text/html"> element but it wasn't effective.

Comment: @BalusC i still see it, but it didn't show.

Comment: You mean, you see the unparsed/unexecuted `<p:gmap>` exactly like that in generated HTML output? In otherwords, PrimeFaces didn't do its job of generating HTML output like as standard JSF `<h:xxx>` components? Well, how exactly did you install PrimeFaces?